# Microsoft Word Collapse and Expand Button

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, macros, microsoft, macro-button

Is it possible to add a button to an Word document for collapsing and expanding the headings within the document. I am looking to create a document that is easy to navigate for those who are not to familiar with word. I understand you can right click and collapse/expand but this isn't instinctive to someone who isn't familiar with using Word

Comment: When you hover the mouse on a heading, there is an arrow next on its left to expand/collapse. Why can't you use that?

Comment: I have 15 sub headings to a main heading, I would like to have a button that only opens and closes all sub headings within that main heading and not have to click on all 15 sub headings. But also there and similar main headings further down so the expand all headings option does not suit

Comment: AFAIK, there is not a control to do what you want. Consider using Outline View. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm Also there is the Navigation Pane. You could, also, place in the document a partial TOC to your headings.